# What materials should I use to make a suborbital amateur rocket and where can I buy them?

Tags: reentry, materials, sub-orbital, amateur-rocketry

I’m trying to make a suborbital rocket to get some pictures of the Earth but I’m not sure what material’s to use and where to get them. I’ve been thinking of titanium for the shell but I’m not sure where to buy it and where to get a thick enough tube for fuel.

Also, I don’t have to reach suborbital straight away, I just need something to start testing rockets so I can eventually get there.

Comment: Hi and *welcome to Space!* Your question "how to I build a rocket that will go to space?" is way too broad for this site. Have a look around and see how specific questions are generally written and how they can usually be answered with clear, concise answers.

Comment: Find your local amateur rocker group and join it.

Comment: Note that if you have follow-up questions about rocket fuel, that [those are off-topic](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/why-cant-i-ask-my-question-about-amateur-space-projects-and-development) here

Comment: Estes makes, or has made, rockets which incorporate cameras. They're certainly suborbital and allow you to get pictures of (portions of) the Earth.

Comment: Amateur rules often specifically exclude metal from your airframe https://ausrocketry.com.au/launching-model-rockets so a titanium body would add legal requirements. One reason for this is that a metal rocket body is just a pipe bomb that has not exploded yet.

Comment: You don’t need a rocket to take pictures of the Earth; a weather balloon can get very high, and is made of much less challenging materials.

Answer (score 5):

Titanium is too ambitious for a first project. It's difficult to machine and weld. It's also overkill: even many orbital rockets use aluminium hulls. Amateur rockets generally use plastic bodies.

To get a good start in amateur rocketry, join an amateur rocket group. Start by launching a few Estes rockets, and scale up from there.

Comment: Other materials to consider: Blue Tube, fiberglass, other composites.